# Why are `/dev/ptmx` and `/dev/pts/ptmx` not device files?

Tags: linux, pseudoterminal

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492304/674 says

> On Linux, using devpts, there is no master device file. The process on the master end uses a file descriptor, which it gets by opening ptmx, but there’s no corresponding device node.

Did the author refer to `/dev/ptmx` or `/dev/pts/ptmx`?

Why are `/dev/ptmx` and `/dev/pts/ptmx` not device files? What types of files are they?

What is the difference between `/dev/ptmx` and `/dev/pts/ptmx`?

Thanks.

On Lubuntu 18.04

```
$ file /dev/ptmx 
/dev/ptmx: character special (5/2)
$ file /dev/pts/ptmx 
/dev/pts/ptmx: character special (5/2)

$ sudo su

# stat -L /dev/fd/3 3<> /dev/pts/ptmx
  File: /dev/fd/3
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   character special file
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 2           Links: 1     Device type: 5,2
Access: (0000/c---------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-11-21 13:39:10.544000218 -0500
Modify: 2018-11-21 13:39:10.544000218 -0500
Change: 2018-11-21 13:39:10.544000218 -0500
 Birth: -

# stat -L /dev/fd/3 3<> /dev/ptmx
  File: /dev/fd/3
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 87          Links: 1     Device type: 5,2
Access: (0666/crw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    5/     tty)
Access: 2019-01-06 07:19:54.372098540 -0500
Modify: 2019-01-06 07:19:54.372098540 -0500
Change: 2018-11-21 13:39:30.372098540 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Comment: They're not? Then why `file` command say they are? I double checked, they really are. It's just how you rephrase your  language, nothing big deal, almost every thing is used through a file descriptor on linux, but "file" is not well-defined . See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/pts.4.html.

Comment: I can't check this right now, but does `stat -L /dev/fd/3 3<> /dev/ptmx` show a major/minor of 5 and 2, or something else?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes. updated.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `/dev/ptmx` will multiplex a new pty pair on opening it, no matter what path is used for that; your command will actually create 2 pseudo-terminal pairs.

Answer (score 2):

The context was “A pseudoterminal has a pair of master and slave.” When I wrote “there is no master device file”, I meant that there is no device node in the file system corresponding to the master end of a pseudoterminal connection, unlike the slave end. I wasn’t referring to either `/dev/ptmx` or `/dev/pts/ptmx`.

`/dev/ptmx` and `/dev/pts/ptmx` are device nodes, as indicated by their type in the output of `ls` or `stat`. They have the same major and minor, which means they provide access to the same device.

See [JdeBP’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492849/86440) to [Where does `/dev/pts/ptmx` come from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492823/86440) for the history of both device nodes (and the reason why there are two on Linux nowadays).